# NHibernate ISessionFactory that enables filters on OpenSession

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

I have been trying to create an **ISessionFactory** that has a list of filters as a property (so it can be specified in the XML configuration) and enables each of the filters whenever OpenSession() is called.

Unfortunately, I have been stymied at every turn.  I've subclassed **LocalSessionFactoryObject** and **SimpleDelegatingSessionFactory**, mixed-and-matched every way I can think of, but there's always some syntax or run-time error that keeps it from working.

Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

[**Update**]

I've been asked to provide some code to illustrate my issue.  I don't think that's really relevant to the question I'm asking, but I can elaborate:

I figured that to make sure the filters are enables whenever a new session is opened I'd have to have my own *OpenSession* method.  It seemed the best way to do this was to subclass **DelegatingSessionFactory**, add the filter-list property and a method like this

```
public new ISession OpenSession()
{
    var rtn = base.OpenSession();
    foreach (var filter in filters)
        rtn.EnableFilter(filter);
    return rtn;
}
```

When I had **Spring** construct this as my **ISessionFactory** object, though, I got runtime errors about not having an exception translator.  So, I figured I'm better off also subclassing **LocalSessionFactoryObject** and having it create an **ISessionFactory** of my new type with the filter list, rather than the default type.  To do this I tried to override *NewSessionFactory*, but then I got a runtime error about not having a **DbProvider** defined, and when I tried to copy the code that handles this from **LocalSessionFactoryObject** I got a bunch of syntax errors because of the scope of some members...

In short, something that seemed like it should be simple -- and that in fact I rather expected many to have done before me -- turned in a coding safari.  That's why I'm looking for someone who's already done it, or who at least understands the framework better than I do.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of the question you are asking here. Are you saying you have some filters defined on the XML mappings and want to enable them, not at the query level but at the session level? What are these `filters` you are mentioning? Can you provide us with more detail?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to call session.EnableFilter() whenever the session is opened -- which is done by OpenSessionInView -- rather than having every method that uses the session include the EnableFilter() call.  The filter itself is nothing special:  "ACTIVE = 1".  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

But do the filters need to be active always? If that is the case, then you should instead be using Where restrictions on the entity and/or collections.

Comment: No, there are some rare occasions when we don't want to enable the filters.

Comment: I am looking for something very similar. Whenever the session created, filters should be enabled. If you got the solution please share it.